# Session variable is lost with larger files

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

We provide a web application that allows users to analyse a source file. The general structure is as follows:

1. the user is requested to upload the file (which is stored in a session variable);
2. the user is requested to make a couple of choices based on the input file provided;
3. the user is provided with an analysis.

This has been working perfectly, until recently a larger file (15 MB) was uploaded. The file is still stored in a session variable from step 1 to step 2. However, clicking any button in step 2 results in the session variable being lost. Smaller files work as intended.

We did some research, but the following should not be the issue:

- We are not dealing with timeout issues;
- We did not set a Virtual Memory Limit in our DefaultAppPool and we have enough RAM available.

To further clarify, I've included some code below.

At step 2 we check the presence of one of the session variables (with key CasesSessionKey) and create another one (with key GraphSessionKey). This is both done succesfully:

```cs
if (!HttpContext.Session.Keys.Contains(CasesSessionKey))
            {
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }

            var processMiningResult = HttpContext.Session.GetFromJson<ProcessMiningResult>(CasesSessionKey);
            HttpContext.Session.SetAsJson(GraphSessionKey, graph);
```

Then, at step 3 no session variables are present. Smaller files do not have this issue:

```cs
            if (!HttpContext.Session.Keys.Contains(CasesSessionKey) ||
                !HttpContext.Session.Keys.Contains(GraphSessionKey))
            {
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
```

I expected that both session variables are still available at step 3, but this isn't the case. What is causing this issue?

Comment: are the files taking longer to load that the session permits as a timeout?

Comment: Are you trying to upload the entire content of the file into session variable?

Comment: Timeout is not the issue. And yes, we are uploading the entire content of the file into a session variable. We chose to do it that way since we are dealing with sensitive data and would like to keep everything in-memory.

Comment: Whatever the key is, I'd search the code for anyplace where it's used. Whatever method that is, I'd look for whatever that method is called. It's possible that it has nothing to do with the size - it's just getting overwritten or deleted - but because it's unusually large we're inclined to suspect that it's the size.